# How will I use Throughput Shaping Timer from Jmeter API using java code?

Tags: jmeter

I want to use the Throughput Shaping Timer using JMeter API in my java code.

My purpose is to to use Throughput Shaping Timer via JMeter API  in my code programmatically.

I have already referenced the class file called VariableThroughputTimer.java by adding it to the source directory of my project folder.

Here is a part of my code snippet:

```
   //   VariableThroughputTimer
    VariableThroughputTimer timer = new VariableThroughputTimer();
    timer.setEnabled(true);
    timer.setName("VariableThroughputTimer");
    timer.setProperty("Start RPS", 1);
    timer.setProperty("End RPS", 1000);
    timer.setProperty("Duration", 60);
    timer.setComment("Table below sets request rate shcedule ant preview graph instantly shows effect of changes.");
    timer.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector.class.getName());
    timer.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.TransactionsPerSecondGui.class.getName());


    // Thread Group
    ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
    threadGroup.setName("Thread Group");
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(4);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
    threadGroup.setDuration(1);;
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(PublishController);
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

    // Test Plan
    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("IOT_Jmeter");
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
    testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

    // HTTP Request Sampler and Header Manager
    HashTree httpRequestTree = new HashTree();
    httpRequestTree.add(mqttConnectSampler);
    httpRequestTree.add(mqttpubSampler);
    httpRequestTree.add(csvDataSet);
    httpRequestTree.add(timer);
```

So whenever, I try to execute the code. It doesn't execute.

Here are the logs from my eclipse IDE:

```
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [main] INFO  StandardJMeterEngine:453 - Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [main] INFO  StandardJMeterEngine:513 - Starting 4 threads for group Thread Group.
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [main] INFO  StandardJMeterEngine:523 - Thread will continue on error
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [main] INFO  ThreadGroup:222 - Starting thread group... number=1 threads=4 ramp-up=1 perThread=250.0 delayedStart=false
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [main] INFO  ThreadGroup:236 - Started thread group number 1
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [main] INFO  StandardJMeterEngine:464 - All thread groups have been started
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] INFO  JMeterThread:705 - Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] INFO  FileServer:265 - Stored: C:\Users\angshuman.basak\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.0\csvDataNew.csv
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] INFO  VariableThroughputTimer:304 - No further RPS schedule, asking threads to stop...
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] INFO  VariableThroughputTimer:319 - Stopping gracefuly threads of Thread Group : Thread Group
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] INFO  JMeterThread:797 - Stopping: Thread Group 1-2
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] INFO  JMeterThread:797 - Stopping: Thread Group 1-3
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] INFO  JMeterThread:797 - Stopping: Thread Group 1-4
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] INFO  JMeterThread:797 - Stopping: Thread Group 1-1
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] WARN  VariableThroughputTimer:147 - No free threads available in current Thread Group Thread Group, made 0 samples/s for expected rps 1.0 samples/s, increase your number of threads
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] INFO  JMeterThread:324 - Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2019-02-12 16:13:29 [Thread Group 1-2] INFO  JMeterThread:705 - Thread started: Thread Group 1-2
2019-02-12 16:13:29 [Thread Group 1-2] INFO  JMeterThread:324 - Thread finished: Thread Group 1-2
2019-02-12 16:13:29 [Thread Group 1-3] INFO  JMeterThread:705 - Thread started: Thread Group 1-3
2019-02-12 16:13:29 [Thread Group 1-3] INFO  JMeterThread:324 - Thread finished: Thread Group 1-3
2019-02-12 16:13:29 [Thread Group 1-4] INFO  JMeterThread:705 - Thread started: Thread Group 1-4
2019-02-12 16:13:29 [Thread Group 1-4] INFO  JMeterThread:324 - Thread finished: Thread Group 1-4
2019-02-12 16:13:29 [main] INFO  StandardJMeterEngine:223 - Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-02-12 16:13:29 [main] INFO  FileServer:485 - Close: C:\Users\angshuman.basak\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.0\csvDataNew.csv
2019-02-12 16:13:29 [main] INFO  Summariser:327 - summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

The above Summariser represent that the test didn't get executed. From the above logs the Variable Throughput Timer fetches the below:

```
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] INFO  VariableThroughputTimer:304 - No further RPS schedule, asking threads to stop...
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] INFO  VariableThroughputTimer:319 - Stopping gracefully threads of Thread Group: Thread Group
2019-02-12 16:13:28 [Thread Group 1-1] WARN  VariableThroughputTimer:147 - No free threads available in current Thread Group Thread Group, made 0 samples/s for expected rps 1.0 samples/s, increase your number of threads
```

I want to execute the code with Throughput Shaping Timer programmatically. I would like to have the correct code for VariableThroughputTimer if my implementation is incorrect or resolve the execution issue.

Your aid is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you plan to reach 1000 requests per second with 4 threads only? It might be possible only if you have 4 milliseconds response time which is highly unlikely.

As per log entry you should

> Thread Group Thread Group, made 0 samples/s for expected rps 1.0 samples/s, **increase your number of threads**`

also make sure to configure underlying [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) to iterate **forever**.

Going forward consider using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) which can be connected with the Throughput Shaping Timer using [Schedule Feedback](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) function so JMeter will be able to kick off extra threads if the current amount is not enough to reach/maintain the target throughput. Check out [Using JMeter’s Throughput Shaping Timer Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Thread Group** configuration isn't appropriate according to your required **Throughput**. As your required throughput is `1000 RPS`, you need at-least `1000 threads` if the response time is `1 second`. If the response time is `0.5 seconds` then you need `500 threads` to achieve `1000 RPS`. So, You can't achieve that 1000 RPS by using only `4 threads`. Your response time have to be `.004 seconds`(4 ms) to achieve 1000 RPS using only 4 threads which is an unusual thing.

You have set your test duration only for 1 seconds which is also wrong for this case.